# Programmatically produce a paper shadow

Tags: javascript, css, shadow

On [this page](http://armavia.am/), you'll notice a shadow on the left border. It's done with an image. Is it possible to produce shadows like this entirely programmatically with CSS or anything else.

Comment: use the box-shadow property in css

Comment: Ironic comments are.. ironic :)

Comment: @Jared Farrish, I'm not building a site. I'm learning from sites. Also, what's the problem with asking questions. Isn't this what SO is for? ;)

Comment: Never said there was anything wrong with it. ;)

Comment: @sameold, Anything you're still looking for here?

Answer (score 6):

### You're looking for the `box-shadow` property in CSS3.

The canonical syntax is:

```
#example1 {
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}
```

You can support in Mozilla and WebKit with the following syntax:

```
#example1 {
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}
```

(These examples are from http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/ )

You can get compatibility for this in Internet Explorer with [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/)

Answer (score 4):

the box-shadow property [available in css3](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) can help you solve this problem

for browser compatibility you can set it this way,

```
#div {
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}
```

the properties are

left right blur and color